# StyleCop and = space

Tags: stylecop

I am running StyleCop (which btw I completely recommend if you want to deliver high quality code)...

I have this line

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable=false)]
```

**update tried this too**

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
```

StyleCop is reporting an error

```
Warning 2   SA1003: The spacing around the symbol '=' is invalid.
```

If this is invalid, what is valid?

Comment: Maybe it's the spacing between IsNullable=false that was the problem?

Comment: [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)], Thank you Matt :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come on y'all. ;) Matt had it in the comment.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
```

Comment: Amazing how sometimes you overlook the details :)

Answer (score 5):

Make life easy on yourself and just CTRL+K+D the file in VS.

Comment: Cool -- I see changes being made, but what does this shortcut actually do?

Comment: @Isaac Lyman The same as menu item: Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document